# when i update state in react, is this how i avoid mutating the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I read that I should be using functional setState and also not mutating my state.

Is this how that works?

```
onChangeTextInput = ({ name, value }) => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      form: {
        ...state.form,
        [name]: value
      }
    }));
  };
```

Comment: Yes :) You are doing it right.

Comment: In case you get confused from the provided answer or answers, when you set a state property, this updated property is merged with the state. So, the unnecessary part here is `...state`. You can just set the `form` property..

Answer (score 1):

```
this.setState({ form: {...this.state.form, [name]: value }});
```

The above is the simpler form for what you trying to do. When it says don't mutate directly, what it means is dont do something like `this.state.form = newObj`

Comment: `state` is undefined in your code. OP is doing right.

Comment: Now, you should use functional `setState` here since you are depending on the current state in your code. Again, OP is doing right :)

Comment: @devserkan: i think just change it to this.state.form right? Anyway my answer was exactly your point which to point out that `...state` is unnecessarily and we can directly pass in the object to setState instead of function

Comment: Yeah, `...state` part unnecessary in the OP's code but it does not harm anything. Since you have provided an answer, if you change your code with the functional `setState` and explain why `...state` part is unnecessary it can be accepted by the OP. Functional one is necessary here instead of providing an object. Because we depend on the current state here. So, we should avoid setting the state directly.